# Failed to cast argument 2 to scalar constant when using replace()

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to use `replace` when the 2nd argument to the function is a column field:

```
replace("bla", column1Field, orignalString)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
replace(): failed to cast argument 2 to scalar constant
```

Why am I getting this error and how to still use the column field with those functions?

Comment: Hi @Ace, please see my updated answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update from Jul 2021:**

The `replace()` function has been replaced with [`replace_regex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/replace-regex-function) (just note that the order of the arguments changed). `replace_regex()` expects a regex lookup, and it must be a constant because Kusto "compiles" it, and it would be bad performance-wise to do it per record.

And there's a new [`replace_string()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/replace-string-function) function that lets you do exactly what you want: replace one string with another (both can be non-const). So in your case, you should use `replace_string(orignalString, "bla", column1Field)`

**Old answer:**

The 2nd argument of `replace()` must be a constant because Kusto "compiles" it, and it would be bad performance-wise to do it per record.

An example (from the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/replacefunction)):

```
range x from 1 to 5 step 1
| extend str=strcat('Number is ', tostring(x))
| extend replaced=replace(@'is (\d+)', @'was: \1', str)
```

As you can see, the second parameter contains `\1` which will take the value in str, that matches what's inside the `()`s in the regex that's the first parameter.